# Accessing ngFor variable in template outside context

Tags: angular

consider following code:

```
<div [ngClass]="var.state">
  <div *ngFor="let var of vars">{{var.text}}</div>
</div>
```

Which will fail, due to scoping of `var` only inside `ngFor` loop context. As you see I need some partition of `var` data outside of loop context. Is it possible to enclose it in some template variable of by any other hack?

Note: I know, that this is behavior by design, and above code is simplified (`var` is needed few levels up).

Comment: I don't get what you want. What would you expect the state would be? you could do vars[0].state or vars[vars.length -1].state

Comment: `var` does not exist outside of `ngFor` loop scope, they are not available in place I'd like to reach them

Answer (score 1):

Why don't simply do that ?

```
<div *ngFor="let var of vars" [ngClass]="var.state">
  <div>{{var.text}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that i presented way simplified example and hosting `ngFor` on level above is not the case. Just think about situation, when you generating table (one `ngFor`) and inside table you generating cells (second `ngFor`). State of single cell can affect row, but data for cells are coming from nested `ngFor`

Comment: this should be the opt approach but he wants to use it outside the scope.

Comment: @Tomas Not sure I understand what you want to achieve. You should provite a complete example. You're actual ticket does not make sens. What is the expected value of `state` in `var.state` ? `vars[0]`, `vars[1]`, ... ?

Comment: @Alexander, as @Manish mention, I need to access template var outside of it's `*ngFor` scope. While your answer makes perfect sense if I could host `*ngFor` in upper tag (uppet `div` in example) but my use case is I ddon't wont do duplicate some higher elements, while nested variable still have some effect on them. In my case `var.state` would be simply `undefined` and cause `TypeError` due to scoping

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use it in **component.ts** file and store the required one as variable and using in on the html.

> app.component.ts

```
flag:any;
ngOnInit(){
  vars.forEach(var=>{
       if(var=="some-condition")
           //yes set this flag
  });
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="flag">
  <div *ngFor="let var of vars">{{var.text}}</div>
</div>
```

Because you can only get the values of the list by getting inside the list.

Comment: Using @HostBinding may work as well, just as a side note and if it's wort effort to encapsulate this partition of template in separate component

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div *ngFor="let var of vars">
      <div [ngClass]="var.state">
       <div >{{var.text}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```